# Bootstrap - Multiple Button Dropdown Menus Interfering With Each Other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code - 3 Button Dropdown Menus are next to each other, each with their own unique ID.  However, pressing the caret on the first 2 do nothing, while pressing the 3rd caret makes the drop-down menu on the first appear.  Any reason why?  Am I missing something that adds uniqueness to the Button Group?  A bug in Bootstrap?

```
<div class="btn-group" id="all-sectors">
    <button class="btn btn-larger btn-primary title">All Sectors</button>
    <button class="btn btn-larger btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="all">All Cameras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="camera-Joe0">camera-Joe0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="North-Joe0">North-Joe0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="East-Joe0">East-Joe0</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" id="all-grids">
    <button class="btn btn-larger btn-primary title">All Grids</button>
    <button class="btn btn-larger btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="all">All Cameras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="camera-Joe0">camera-Joe0</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" id="all-cameras">
    <button class="btn btn-larger btn-primary title">All Cameras</button>
    <button class="btn btn-larger btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="all">All Cameras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="camera-filter" data-filter-type="camera-Joe0">camera-Joe0</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: they work fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/cLrYr/

Comment: I found the issue in my code, but it still seems somewhat buggy on Bootstrap's part.  I made each of the 3 btn-group have a float:left; in my CSS file, and that seemed to have been the cause of the problem.  Removing that CSS made it work again.

Comment: if you want to place them side by side you can use the `.btn-toolbar` container class straight from the bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, the .btn-toolbar did was I was looking for.  Thanks!  I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my CSS.  I added a

```
float:left;
```

to each .btn-group which stopped the first two from working properly.  I should have wrapped them in a

```
.btn-toolbar
```

wrapper instead.